# Is it possible to access an external class' member variable in page.xaml.cs?

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app, and I have two xaml pages. From the first one, I embed two app bar links to select an image from gallery or capture an image using the camera. I would like the image chosen on the first page to be displayed on a second page, with the app bar buttons showing a confirm yes or no. As of now, I have an image control on the first page (barcodeImage) that gets updated with the choice.

MainPage.xaml

```
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="welcome">
            <ScrollViewer Name="sv1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <StackPanel Height="1100">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Random text here.
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                        <Image Height="150" Margin="28,30,168,0" Name="barcodeImage" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
    </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
        void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            barcodeImage.Source = bmp;
        }
    }
```

Confirm.xaml

```
        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image Margin="64,36,57,100" x:Name="barcodeImageFinal" Stretch="Fill" />
    </Grid>
```

I'd like barcodeImageFinal to display the final bitmap. How can I make this work? Thanks for looking :)

Comment: I don't understand how the title relates to what you've wrtten. Or what the question you're asking is.

Comment: I believe the question is a possible solution to my problem, outlined in the body above. I am open to alternatives, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to create a bitmap in a member of `MainPage` and then access it from `Confirm`.  One approach would be to create a public static property of some class for your bitmap.  For example, maybe create `public static BitmapImage FinalBitmap` in your `App`.  Then you could set the value of the property in your `cameraCaptureTask_Completed` and then create a `Loaded` handler in your `Confirm` class that sets image source to the stored bitmap.

I think the answer to your question title is yes if you make the member static, although the other class isn't really "external".  A normal class member won't be accessible because you don't have an instance of that class.

Comment: Are you suggesting I create a class in my app.xaml.cs file
    public static FinalBitmap
    {
        BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    }
and then save the chose image to myBitmapImage.Source in MainPage.xaml, and then reference the same myBitmapImage.Source in Confirm.xaml.cs?

Comment: You don't need to create a class, just a static property of type BitmapImage to save a reference to the bitmap.  Then your confirmation page can access it.  I noticed I made an error in my answer which caused this to be less clear than it could have been.  I will edit it to correct.

Comment: In my example I suggested you create the property in the App class in App.xaml.cs but you could also create it in the MainPage class.  The key point is that it is static so that the other page can reference it without an instance of MainPage.

Comment: Interesting... Thanks man, I will give this a shot once I get home and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: This totally worked. All I had to do was define
public static BitmapImage chosenImage = new BitmapImage();
in my MainPage class, set the source in my cameraCaptureTask_Completed method, and call it in Confirm, just like you said. Thank you so much :)